# how to add my own tab/category to explorer and manage files?

Tags: c#, api

How do I add something like this?
And manage to put files there and stuff (Like onedrive does it)

[image: Picture of categories file explorer]

Comment: You have to implement a [cloud provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/integrate-cloud-storage).

Comment: I feel your pain in searching for a solution when you don't know what the components are called.  I think your screenshot should have shown the _OneDrive_ icon as opposed to the _This PC_ icon.  I think the piece of info that you were missing has already been identified by Raymond Chen--that OneDrive (or Dropbox, Creative Cloud, etc.) are _cloud providers_ and appear as top-level items in the Navigation Pane of Windows Explorer.

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to make it a custom category of files (stored anyway) instead of just something form from the cloud?